# Get id of top viewable table row when Div Scroll event fires

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table inside a scrollable div tag. When a user scrolls down I would like to capture the ID for the visible TR using jQuery. There could be several hundred records returned. How can I find the top visible table row id using jQuery?

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="overflow-y: scroll" class="scrollDiv">
   <table id="mainTable" style="table-layout:fixed" height="900px">
      <tr id="0">
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="1">
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2">
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>

   </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".scrollDiv").scroll(function(){
   var rowNumber = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
   //the above returns the top row visible or not. I want the first visible row.
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code as posted wont work at all since `$(this).closest('tr')...` if referring to the closest ancestor of the enclosing `<div>` which does not exist.  You need to get the `.scrollTop()` of the `div` and compare it with the heights of the elements within the `div`.

I've created a [simple fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zc30qhxz/) that shows how it can work (in this case the scroll container contains divs - you will need to adapt for you table rows and which cell text you want to return

html

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

script

```
$("#mainDiv").scroll(function () {
  var rows = $(this).children('div');
  var offset = $(this).scrollTop();
  var visibleIndex = 0;
  var height = 0;
  rows.each(function (index, item) {
    if (offset == 0) {
      height = 0;
      visibleIndex = 0
      return false;
    }
    height += $(this).height();
    if (height > offset) {
      visibleIndex = index + 1;
      height = 0;
      return false;
    }
})
$('#message').text('The text of the first fully visible div is ' + rows.eq(visibleIndex).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking into this now.

Comment: Thanks :) It helped for my needs. If any one require data of the not visible rows they can choose index of rows not the visibleIndex.